# Trying to solve system of 4 equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$$x = 0.09 x + 0.6p y + (1.3p - p^2) z,$$ 
$$y= 0.49 x + 0.16 y + 0.7 z,$$
$$z = 0.42 x + (0.84 - 0.6p) y + (p^2 - 2p + 1) z,$$
$$x + y + z = 1$$

When I attempt to use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%20%3D%200.09%20x%20%2B%200.6p%20y%20%2B%20%281.3p%20-%20p%5E2%29%20z%2C%20y%3D%200.49%20x%20%2B%200.16%20y%20%2B%200.7%20z%2C%20z%20%3D%200.42%20x%20%2B%20%280.84%20-%200.6p%29%20y%20%2B%20%28p%5E2%20-%202p%20%2B%201%29%20z%2C%20x%20%2B%20y%20%2B%20z%20%3D%201) to solve this, the system starts giving me values of $p$ for some reason. I just want the equations $x$, $y$, and $z$ in terms of (unknown) $p$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to help me with this.

Comment: Try: Take first 3 equation from your system, and check is such homogeneous system (with first 3 equation) having nontrivial solutions. We know that homogeneous system $\left( AX=0 \right)$ is having nontrivial solutions **iff** determinant of matrix $A$ is zero, i.e. $\det(A)=0$. Finally, if you will have one-parametric solution(s), put them into 4-th equation of the original system to find its solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A simplistic approach*

From $(1)$ extract $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Plug the result in $(2)$ and solve for $y$ as a function of $x$. These two steps give
$$y=\frac{7 \left(10 p^2-13 p-13\right) x}{24 p (5 p-9)}\qquad \qquad z=\frac{7 (5 p-13) x}{20 p (5 p-9)}$$

Plug in $(3)$ to get
$$\frac{49 (p-1) (5 p-13) x}{200 p (5 p-9)}=0$$ You cannot have $x=0$ since this would make $x=y=z=0$ which cannot satisfy $(4)$.

So, the only possibilities are $p=1$ or $p=\frac {13} 5$ Now, consider each case and use $(4)$ to solve.